# How to send data to a redirected URL spring mvc

Tags: servlets, redirect, spring-mvc, request, response

I have an URL which redirects to another URL when called. I would like to pass some data along with the redirection.

For example I have this method:

```
@RequestMapping("efetuaEnvioEmail")
    public String efetuaEnvioEmail(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("efetuaEnvioEmail");
        return "redirect:inicio";
    }
```

Which redirects to this one:

```
@RequestMapping("inicio")
    public String Inicio(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        return "Inicio";
    }
```

I would like to pass some data informing that everything went fine on the first method.

I have tried some methods of HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse but I couldn't have anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `RedirectAttributes` to pass any data between handler methods:

```
@RequestMapping("efetuaEnvioEmail")
public String efetuaEnvioEmail(RedirectAttributes rattrs) {
    rattrs.addAttribute("string", "this will be converted into string, if not already");
    rattrs.addFlashAttribute("pojo", "this can be POJO as it will be stored on session during the redirect");
    return "redirect:inicio";
}

@RequestMapping("inicio")
public String Inicio(@ModelAttribute("pojo") String pojo) {
    System.out.println(pojo);
    return "Inicio";
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! I'm having some problems though. I'm using spring mvc 3.0.5 and it seems to not have RedirectAttributes  in this version.. I have downloaded spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar and it has the RedirectAttributes class.. but i'm having a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: In my case I just wanna know that inicio is called by efetuaEnvioEmail.. and not by any other URL redirect.. so any other solution would be welcome as well :)

Comment: @FelipeMosso This may help you - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/

Comment: @FelipeMosso I strongly suggest you to upgrade to Spring 3.2+ and solve whatever problem you will find (e.g. by asking a question here on SO). Versions 3.0 and 3.1 are not as mature and "feature complete" as 3.2.

Comment: And btw. it should be possible to add query parameters also like this: `return "redirect:inicio?email=foo";`

Comment: thanks for your answer! I updated my framework but it crashed processing with JSON. As I don't wanna to waste too much time on it, I ended up passing the data by the session and, once the page was redirected, I make the session invalid. I will give the answer cause this is the best way to do what I was trying to! thanks!